# Vertex displacement on sphere break the mesh

Tags: math, 3d, three.js, shader, vertex-shader

I'm trying to make a simple noise effect on a sphere with shaders.
I tried to use [ashima's perlin noise](https://github.com/ashima/webgl-noise) but the effect wasn't what I expected so I create my own shader based on Phong.

[image: custom phong shader with broken dispalcement]

Here is what I get with this code in my **vertex shader**:

```
attribute int index;
uniform float time;

vec3 newPosition = position + normal * vec3(sin((time * 0.001) * float(index)) * 0.05);

gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(newPosition, 1.0);
```

where `index` is the index of the vertex and `time` the current elapsed time.

The noise effect is exactly what I expected but the sphere mesh is open...

How can I keep this effect and keep the sphere mesh closed?

Comment: Can we see the fragment shader too ? Personally I do not see how only a vertex position transformation could create a white color artifact. Except if you would be clearing the screen to white. So problem is either in another part of your vertex shader or in the fragment shader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your sphere contains duplicated vertices. Get rid of them and your shader will works well. Or get rid of your shader dependency on "index".

Comment: It's the standard sphere geometry of Three.js

Comment: Try to comment out "* float(index)) * 0.05". If holes will disappear then Three.js contains a shitty sphere.

Comment: If I do that I cancel the wave effect and get only a global scale. But yes, hole disappear...

Comment: Ok. Try to use position.x+position.y+position.z instead of index.

Comment: Oh!... Great idea... I'm gonna try that tomorrow

Comment: Then the only way is to get rid of vertex duplicates.

Comment: Like importing better sphere geometry from Blender ?
Is it possible to parse three js sphere ? Cause a 40x40 sphere contains 1681 vertices and not 1600...

Comment: I am not into THREE.js but from a quick look on its documentation I may suppose that you can create custom geometry and copy existing geometry into it and perform various processing of geometry in-between. For example, you can copy only unique vertices, built mapping of old (non-unique) indices to new (unique) and copy updated triangles accordingly with new indices.